# Contenteditable attribute

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

How can I configure maximum number of rows in `contenteditable` attribute?
I want to stop use after they will reach his capacity of characters for send in POST method.

I'm just using HTML 5. It's a new atributte, you can google it. It's value can be true or false. Contenteditable is not using windows enccoded new lines like: `\r\n`, but using creating divs and adding `<br>` tags to it.

Comment: You should really **give us more information** on you environment (any framework ? do you use a plugin for the editable content ? ...). Tell us also what you tried, what is your code (HTML and js)... Yet, if you have no clue, you can use jeditable jquery plugin with a character counter : http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/custom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just run some JavaScript on the element, like so:

```
function check_len(){
    //disable editing, or something here
    if (element.innerHTML.length >= POST_limit)
        alert('you have reached the post limit');
}
```

And you could attach it to a keyup handler

```
element.addEventListener('keyup',check_len,false);
```

Comment: Thanks. But my main problem is not in it. My main problem is:

Comment: Sorry, it appears you never finished your comment. What I'm getting is that you want to remove the contentEditable attribute once the character length (el.innerHTML.length) is greater than your character limit (POST_limit).